# Writing to event log - how to set user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

From my ASP.Net MVC application I'm logging certain operations to the web server's Application log using EventLog.WriteEntry:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
// Code to build event log message removed
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Application name", s.ToString(),
    System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

This is working fine, but the resulting log entry lists the User as "N/A":

[image]

Is there any way I can set the user property in code?  None of the EventLog.WriteEntry overloads allow this as far as I can see.  I can log the username in the body of the message but this would be useful for filtering purposes.

Comment: you could just include the username in the text of your log entry, if you need that info. If you look at a windows event log, 99% of the entries tend not to include the user field

Comment: I don't recommend using the `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` API to perform logging within an application (not least because you need Administrative-level permission to create a new `EventSource`). One major drawback is .NET's incomplete support for Resource-string/template-messages. Have you considered using Serilog or `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` instead?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the tip about Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, I'll look into that.